# Encrypted credentials stored in AWS secret manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I have stored below Amazon RDS database secrets in AWS secret manager

> User name - admin,
> Password - Password123

After clicking on Retrieve secret value I got above user name & password with port, engine, host, etc details. Can somehow after clicking Retrieve secret value I get encrypted credentials?

Currently, I have set **Encryption key - aws/secretmanager**, not sure anything needs to be changed here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to encrypt them yourself to achieve that.

The **Encryption Key** you selected is for server-side encryption. If you want the values to be returned to a client (including the Console) encrypted, you'll need to encrypt them before storing them.